# Why alert function before my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my code: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DkkYx/1/)**

```
function ivideos() {
     $('#n1').html('hello');
     $('#n2').html('hello');
     $('#n3').html('hello');
     $('#n4').html('hello');
     $('#n5').html('hello');
}
ivideos();
alert("alert called");
```

I don't know why the alert is called before my function completes. Please help me.

Comment: "*I don't know why the alert is called before my function completes*." It's not. But perhaps the screen simply isn't updated until after the alert is dismissed.

Comment: The alert occurs after your function completes. You can tell because all of the hello text is visible.

Comment: It doesn't. It's just that the browser hasn't quite had chance to render the new HTML before the alert is called.

Comment: @TravisJ In Chrome this isn't the case...

Comment: I guess its optical illusion for you. You need to click on run to get the correct order, you can go to url it appear so.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - I believe you are mistaken. Here is a [chrome screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/aIMBgzU.png)

Comment: Use zero-setTimeout hack for alert function for call it in a new event-cycle

Comment: @TravisJ - No, I'm not mistaken... http://imgur.com/NI2V9xa You can see that jsfiddle hasn't even finished doing its thing.

Comment: @LeeTaylor - The first time that fiddle loads it has a lot of other stuff to deal with. The rendering engine is under duress as the frames are constructed. That example you show is not a good reproduction of this issue at all. You are mistaken. Run it again (**not** while jsfiddle is itself loading for the first time) and you will see the correct order of execution.

Comment: Instead of the alert, try setTimeout(function(){alert("Alert called.")},0);

Answer (score 5):

The call to `alert()` is not made until after the call to `ivideos()` completes, but you do not see the results of the call to `ivideos()` because the browser has not yet repainted the elements.

The code you show all executes in a single event. The browser may choose to wait until it is finished executing that event until it repaints the viewport.

You could use the `setTimeout()` function to push the call to `alert()` to a subsequent event. That way the browser will repaint the elements before the call to `alert()`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("alert called");
}, 0);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6hss/)

Note that `alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()` are unique in that they pause the execution of the current event.

Comment: The use of "thread" when explaining how Javascript works is mostly confusing. There isn't any different threads, there is only one main thread that does everything.

Comment: @Guffa - Point taken. I was a bit careless with my use of the term "thread." I have edited my answer to use the term "event" instead.

Answer (score 3):

The alert isn't called before the function completes.

You are updating elements in the function, and those elements are changed just fine. It's just that the elements and what's visible on the screen is not the same.

While your code is running, nothing else happens in the browser; no other code runs and no events are handled. Once all your code has completed, the browser will resume to handle events, which includes updating the screen according to the changes that has happened while your code was running.

Answer (score 1):

your function is called first. Its just you are not able to see it.
Put an alert inside your function and see the result.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DkkYx/3/)

```
 function ivideos() {
     $('#n1').html('hello');
     $('#n2').html('hello');
     $('#n3').html('hello');
     $('#n4').html('hello');
     $('#n5').html('hello');
     alert('hello');
 }
 ivideos();
  alert("alert called");
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is called in order. When you change the `alert` to a `console.log`, you can see that `ivideos()` is called at first

```
function ivideos() {
    console.log("ivideos begin");
    $('#n1').html('hello');
    $('#n2').html('hello');
    $('#n3').html('hello');
    $('#n4').html('hello');
    $('#n5').html('hello');
    console.log("ivideos end");
}
ivideos();
console.log("alert called");
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DkkYx/6/)

Answer (score 0):

your `"alert"` function has been called after the `"function ivideos"` but due to browser first alert popup is visible then after rendered html.

check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DkkYx/4/)

```
function ivideos() {
    $('#n1').html('hello');
    $('#n2').html('hello');
    $('#n3').html('hello');
    $('#n4').html('hello');
    $('#n5').html('hello');
    alert(1);

}
ivideos();
alert("alert called");
```

first `alert(1)` will be called then after `alert("alert called").`